# How to handle badly formatted messages on the consumer side when working with Spring Integration and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I am currently working on a project involves consuming messages from RabbitMQ brocker. However, I am still new to Spring Integration, AMQP and RabbitMQ. 
I have an issue with consuming malformed messages formats. When my consumer receives a malformed message it returns it back the queue then RabbitMQ sends it back which creates an endless cycle. 
In Spring Integration documentation there are some configuration that can be implemented to that this kind of message are no returned back to the queue.

However I could not understand how to implement that. 
What I want is to be able to configure some kind of bean that has a format like

```
class ExceptionHandler {

   public void handle(Throwable e ) { 

     Logger.log("Some log ... we don't give a Sh** ... ") ; 

   } 

}
```

I've checked section [3.9 Exception Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#exception-handling) 
and [3.15.3 Message Listeners and the Asynchronous Case](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#async-listeners)
but unfortunately I could not understand anything.

So, if you have an example code or a link to one send it I will be greateful.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of try-fails attempts I was able to handle the error. However I am struggling with harboring the exception log now. I don't understand why this is implemented this way. I was able to handle the log issue too. 
It turns that there is another way to say that you don't want to return the message back it is with             `acknowledge-mode="NONE"` attribute. Checkout [10.2 Inbound Channel Adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html) section.This way you don't even need to throw that ugly exception.

```
< bean id="handler" class="MessagesErrorHandler"/>
    < int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter
            error-handler="handler"
            id="idActivityAdapter"
            channel="channelName"
            queue-names="activityQueue"
            />




import org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException;

public class MessagesErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {


    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS ERROR IS HANDLED !!!!");
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(throwable);// this very important
        //so that message don't go back to the queue. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's is one of the correct solution - to throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`, when you decide that the message should not be `requeued`.

There is also `defaultRequeueRejected` on the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, which is `true` by default.

You maybe should to take a look to the [DLX/DLQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) solution to not lose those malformed messages.

Please, share the StackTrace which bothers you.

There is such a code in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`:

```
catch (AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException rejectEx) {
                    /*
                     *  These will normally be wrapped by an LEFE if thrown by the
                     *  listener, but we will also honor it if thrown by an
                     *  error handler.
                     */
                }
```

Comment: Can you provide how to do it with spring ... ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that. "To do" what? Your `MessagesErrorHandler` does the stuff with `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` already. What do you need else?

Answer (score 0):

The `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` is a signal to the container to reject and not requeue the message; by default, it requeues any exception.

Alternatively, you can manually wire up a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean; set `defaultRequeueRejected` to `false` and add it to the adapter using the `container` attribute. Then, all exceptions will cause messages to be rejected and not requeued.

Also, instead of an `error-handler`, you can use an error-channel and throw the `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` from the error flow.